# Is there an 'empty' patch in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I am adding patches according to a list of ones and zeros (e.g. `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`). I want to add patches where there are ones using matplotlib and leave the zeros empty. However, trying the following code raises a list index out of range error:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
self.patches = []
for i, val in enumerate(my_list):
    if val == 1:
        self.patches.append(plt.Rectangle((i, 0), 0.9, 1, angle=0.0,
                                          facecolor='r', edgecolor='w',
                                          linewidth='2.0',
                                          animated=False))
    ax.add_patch(self.patches[i])
```

The only thing I can think of is using an `else` statement in the code above to add a rectangle with the same colour as the background for the zeros. Is there an empty patch object that one could use instead? I want the patches to be in the same position as the ones in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `color='none'` to set all colors (`facecolor` and `edgecolor` to invisible).

alternatively, you can pass `visible=False` to the constructor to hide the patch.

Your loop could be:

```py
my_list = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
patches = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, val in enumerate(my_list):
    p = plt.Rectangle((i, 0), 0.9, 1, angle=0.0,
                                          facecolor='r', edgecolor='w',
                                          linewidth='2.0',
                                          animated=False, visible=bool(val))
    patches.append(p)
    ax.add_patch(p)
```

Comment: Should it be `visible=bool(val)` in the Rectangle options? I think if you use the index value it would give true for all but the first index, but we want true/false for 1/0 in list.

Comment: yes, of course, sorry wasn't paying enough attention. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can pass an empty patch to Matplotlib, but I wouldn't unless for some reason you want matplotlib to know about your missing data:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
self.patches = []
for i, val in enumerate(my_list):
    if val == 1:
        self.patches.append(plt.Rectangle((i, 0), 0.9, 1, angle=0.0,
                                          facecolor='r', edgecolor='w',
                                          linewidth='2.0',
                                          animated=False))
        ax.add_patch(self.patches[i])
    else:
        self.patches.append(None)
```

Comment: If, for example, I was animating these patches with FuncAnimation, updating the list with new positions for the ones, would matplotlib need to know about the missing data (i.e. the zeros). Would this be a good case for appending None?

Comment: Sure thats a reason.  OTOH, you'll need to also toggle visibility.